# Is there a way for me to use a button to print entry's in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi im fairly new to tkinter and python, so i'm just wondering if there is any way for me to use my 'add' button to print 'name' 'email' and 'password' entry's underneath my 'history' Label. The purpose is to help you remember your accounts. Although i don't need the function to keep this data when closed.
Any help would be much appreciated,
Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")
username = "Sam" 
password = "Sam"
#username entry
username_entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=10)

#password entry
password_entry = Entry(root, show='*', borderwidth=10)

username_entry.grid(row=1,column=2)
password_entry.grid(row=2,column=2)

myLabel1 = Label(root,text="Username")
myLabel2 = Label(root,text="Password")

myLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=2, column=0)

def trylogin(): 
    if username == username_entry.get() and password == password_entry.get():
        print("Correct")
        createNewWindow()
    else:
        print("Wrong")

def createNewWindow():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    newWindow.title("Accounts")
    #ENTRY'S
    e1 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)
    e2 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)
    e3 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)

    e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    e2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    e3.grid(row=3, column=2)

    #LABELS
    myLabel1 = Label(newWindow, text="Name")
    myLabel2 = Label(newWindow, text="EMAIL:")
    myLabel3 = Label(newWindow, text="PASSWORD:")
    myLabel4 = Label(newWindow, text="History:")

    myLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    myLabel2.grid(row=2, column=0)
    myLabel3.grid(row=3, column=0)
    myLabel4.grid(row=4, column=1)

def addToWindow():
    myLabel5 = Label(newWindow, text="Name: " + e1.get())
    myLabel6 = Label(newWindow, text="Email: " + e2.get())
    myLabel7 = Label(newWindow, text="Password: " + e3.get())
    
    myLabel5.grid(row=7, column=1)
    myLabel6.grid(row=8, column=1)
    myLabel7.grid(row=9, column=1)


button = Button(newWindow, text="Add", command = addToWindow) 
button.grid(row=4, column=2)


button = Button(root, text="check", command = trylogin) 
button.grid(row=3, column=2)


root.mainloop()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can add a `Treeview` or `Text` widget under the `History` label, then add the input values via a function assigned to the `Add` button.

Comment: Hi !! Do you jest want to keep the credentials of a recent account under your History Label or you want to keep the details of all the accounts?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: Hi @Ayush Jain, right now i'm trying to keep the data of multiple (all accounts) under the history label, Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a function within your createNewWindow function to write the values of the input fields below the history heading. This could be prettier, but you have the values listed.

Code below. Drop this in at line 53 of your script and call the command in your Button function for your add button.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")
username = "username" 
password = "password"
#username entry
username_entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=10)

#password entry
password_entry = Entry(root, show='*', borderwidth=10)

username_entry.grid(row=1,column=2)
password_entry.grid(row=2,column=2)

myLabel1 = Label(root,text="Username")
myLabel2 = Label(root,text="Password")

myLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=2, column=0)

def trylogin(): 
    if username == username_entry.get() and password == password_entry.get():
        print("Correct")
        createNewWindow()
    else:
        print("Wrong")

def createNewWindow():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    newWindow.title("Accounts")
    #ENTRY'S
    e1 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)
    e2 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)
    e3 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)

    e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    e2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    e3.grid(row=3, column=2)

    #LABELS
    myLabel1 = Label(newWindow, text="Name")
    myLabel2 = Label(newWindow, text="EMAIL:")
    myLabel3 = Label(newWindow, text="PASSWORD:")
    myLabel4 = Label(newWindow, text="History:")

    myLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    myLabel2.grid(row=2, column=0)
    myLabel3.grid(row=3, column=0)
    myLabel4.grid(row=5, column=1)
    
    def addToWindow():
        myLabel5 = Label(newWindow, text="Name: " + e1.get())
        myLabel6 = Label(newWindow, text="Email: " + e2.get())
        myLabel7 = Label(newWindow, text="Password: " + e3.get())
        
        myLabel5.grid(row=7, column=1)
        myLabel6.grid(row=8, column=1)
        myLabel7.grid(row=9, column=1)

    button = Button(newWindow, text="Add", command = addToWindow) 
    button.grid(row=4, column=2)

button = Button(root, text="check", command = trylogin) 
button.grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()
#app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Eric when i do this i keep getting an error stating that "newWindow is not defined" am i  doing something wrong?

Comment: Oops...I should have mentioned it’s a function within your createNewWindow function. Did you indent addToWindow so it’s within the function?

Comment: I changed the question, what do you think i should edit?

Comment: Functions in Python need to be indented correctly to be defined. You need to indent addToWindow further right than createNewWindow to work. You are getting a "newWindow is not defined" error because addToWindow is not in the scope of the createNewWindow function. I have edited my answer to make everything clear.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. If you get time, how could i make it so i can make it show multiple accounts.

Comment: Another user had a suggestion up in the comments. You can try that out or maybe just consider adding in a loop. If you have trouble you may want to mark this question answered and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Minor Fix for your req, move the function inside the Newwindow function

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title("Login")
username = "Sam" 
password = "Sam"
#username entry
username_entry = Entry(root, borderwidth=10)

#password entry
password_entry = Entry(root, show='*', borderwidth=10)

username_entry.grid(row=1,column=2)
password_entry.grid(row=2,column=2)

myLabel1 = Label(root,text="Username")
myLabel2 = Label(root,text="Password")

myLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=2, column=0)

def trylogin(): 
    if username == username_entry.get() and password == password_entry.get():
        print("Correct")
        createNewWindow()
    else:
        print("Wrong")

def createNewWindow():
    newWindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    newWindow.title("Accounts")
    #ENTRY'S
    e1 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)
    e2 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)
    e3 = Entry(newWindow, width=50)

    e1.grid(row=1, column=2)
    e2.grid(row=2, column=2)
    e3.grid(row=3, column=2)

    #LABELS
    myLabel1 = Label(newWindow, text="Name")
    myLabel2 = Label(newWindow, text="EMAIL:")
    myLabel3 = Label(newWindow, text="PASSWORD:")
    myLabel4 = Label(newWindow, text="History:")

    myLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    myLabel2.grid(row=2, column=0)
    myLabel3.grid(row=3, column=0)
    myLabel4.grid(row=4, column=1)

    def addToWindow():
        myLabel5 = Label(newWindow, text="Name: " + e1.get())
        myLabel6 = Label(newWindow, text="Email: " + e2.get())
        myLabel7 = Label(newWindow, text="Password: " + e3.get())
        
        myLabel5.grid(row=7, column=1)
        myLabel6.grid(row=8, column=1)
        myLabel7.grid(row=9, column=1)
        
    button = Button(newWindow, text="Add", command = addToWindow) 
    button.grid(row=4, column=2)

button = Button(root, text="check", command = trylogin) 
button.grid(row=3, column=2)


root.mainloop()
app.mainloop()
```